# Color with Excel and Openpyxl

Tags: design-patterns, colors, background, openpyxl, fill

Good morning, I would like to fill some cells with a gray background, the code works and the color as well, in visual code in the preview of the excel file I see the colors correctly, are that when I open the file with excel the background is always black.
any help?

```
        def excel():
                # Writing on a EXCEL FILE
                filename = ("testexcelcolor.xlsx")
                try:
                    wb = load_workbook(filename)
                    ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    headers_row = ['Name SGV PN', 'IVU Nummer']
                    wb = Workbook()
                    ws = wb.active
                    ws.append(headers_row)
                for cols in ws.iter_cols():
                     if cols[-1].value: # need to check the cells have values.
                            # otherwise colors the entire row.
                        cols[-1].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFFFFF", fill_type="solid")
                wb.save(filename)
                ws.append([ivunumber])
                wb.save(filename)
                wb.close()
        excel()
```

Comment: You've only set a background colour. You need to set the foreground because solid fills are also always pattern fills, with the pattern being the foreground.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example? With my code?

Comment: Just change your line to 'fgColor' rather than 'bgColor' --> cols[-1].fill = PatternFill(fgColor="808080", fill_type="solid"). '808080' is a mid grey.

Comment: If you do want to specify both foreground and background then just include both in the line; bgColor="...", fgColor="...". Also you may need to change the font color to read the text depending on how dark the grey you choose.